# Implicit condition for deriving the eccentric Circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Line segments $r_1, r_2$ starting from  a common origin (either overlapping on same side, or placed opposite sides of origin) have a constant product $ =\pm  T^2$ by rotation of the entire common line about origin as pole.

What condition was implied by Euclid in geometric configuration/setting so  we add it (plug it in) to derive equation of a Circle ?

EDIT 1:

Any number of curves can be constructed to have a constant geometric mean of radial segments.

To illustrate what I mean instead of a circle I am taking a simple example of a "returning"  curve (tangent going through origin) as:

$$ r^2 - a^2 \psi = T^2 = r_1 \cdot r_2  \tag{1} $$

where  $r_1,r_2 $ reach up to the curve from origin at same $ \theta$ , $ \psi $ is angle between radius vector and arc tangent. Differentiate with respect to arc, using $ dr/ds = \cos \psi,$

$$ \psi^{\prime} = 2  r \cos \psi/a^2 ;\quad \psi^{\prime \prime}= \cos \psi ^2 - r \sin \psi  \cdot \psi^{\prime}\tag{2} $$

$ \psi $ is angle between radius vector and arc tangent

Taking constants $ a=1, T= 2 $ and corresponding boundary conditions when we  integrate last second order ODE as $ \theta =0, r_i= \sqrt 6, \psi_i= 1$, the desired curve appears as follows with

$$r_1 \cdot r_2 = T^2 \tag{3} $$ everywhere:

EDIT2:

The curve for case $$ T^2 < 0 , \,T^2 = -1.6, \, a=1,\,\theta_i=0, \,r_i=1,\, \psi_i = 1.3 \,rad \tag{4} $$

turns out to be a non-recursive spiral, added below.

[image: Curves with const segments product]

EDIT 3:

The ODE of a standard eccentric circle radius $a$ is given by

$$ \frac{\sin \psi} {r} = \frac{1}{2a} (1-\frac{T^2}{r^2}) \tag{5} $$

In order to investigate further what Euclid may have implied and to investigate further the behavior at nose of curve $T= 2$ ( green curve), I have next taken a changed "linear" ODE in the following form:

$$ \frac{\psi_k} {r_k} = \frac{1}{2a} (1 -\frac{T_k^2}{r_k^2}) \tag{6}$$

They all have same power $ \pm T^2$ periodic with $2 \pi a $ radial width.

and obtained *a $(k)$ series of* concentric "eel" shaped curves of constant width $ 2 \pi a$ between two concentric circles for positive power $T^2$(red). For negative power, $-T^2$ (blue) the curve behavior is similar but how extreme radii values form are still not clear.

[image: Nose_of_Eel]

Comment: Which circle's equation do you desire to derive?

Comment: I desire to know what step/s  missing in the derivation starting with $T^2$ as product of two line segments in beginning and ending up in any known form of the circle.In the beginning the product is given, we do not know what curve it is until derived/proved.

Comment: In Cartesian coordinates, $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is an equation of a circle; in polar coordinates, $r = 1$ is an equation of a circle, and $r=\cos\theta$ is an equation of another circle. I suppose $r^2 - 2 br \pm T^2 =0$ could be the equation of a circle, two concentric circles, or nothing, depending on whether the quadratic equation $r^2 - 2 br \pm T^2 =0$ has one, two, or no solutions in real numbers $r$.

Comment: Sorry if my post did not put it properly. None of the circles you mentioned have a constant product of two $r's$.I could delete the quadratic equation if  not required. I gave it as an example of a quadratic equation whose roots have a constant product of two line segments represented by its  roots, positive or negative.

Comment: @David K There are many curves, other than the circle which share this property.

Comment: You haven't yet described a property. You did not mention in the question that you intended $r_1,r_2$ to be roots of $r^2 - 2 br \pm T^2 =0$, you do not say in what sense "its" equation could possibly "derive" a circle, and I suspect there are many other things that are essential to understand your question that you did not mention. I recommend to edit this question and write it _completely,_ not omitting any essential facts.

Comment: For the case of the origin being *inside* the target circle, this might be the simplest formulation of the question: *Given a function $f(\theta)$ such that $f(\theta + \pi) \cdot f(\theta) = T^2 > 0$, what conditions on $f$ guarantee that the graph of the polar equation $r = f(\theta)$ is a circle?* (For the origin *outside* the circle, use $f(\theta+\pi)\cdot f(\theta) = -T^2 < 0$, and allow the function to be undefined for certain angles.)

Comment: Yes @Blue, Hi  I shall try to reply later on, Too late at night now. I think the inverse question should not, so to say,  beg the question, inputting the answer, I had ( we had!) dealt with it before.

Comment: @Blue Inaccuracies of product of line segments for case $T^2 <0 $ is still bugging. It works for $T^2 >0 $ alright.If not resolved at priority other math logic may be be in jeopardy.Working on it.